# Initialize Map<String, Integer>

Tags: apex, map

Is there a way to initialize a `Map<String, Integer>` without using `put` method ?

I saw that for initalize a `Map<String, String>` :

```
private Map<String, String> myMap = new Map<String, String>('a' => 'John', 'b' => 'Mike', 'c' => 'Eddy');
```

But this doesn't work with my map.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Simply change the parentheses to braces (and change the values to integers).

Before:

```
private Map<String, String> myMap 
  = new Map<String, String>('a' => 'John', 'b' => 'Mike', 'c' => 'Eddy');
```

After:

```
private Map<String, Integer> myMap 
  = new Map<String, Integer>{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3};
```