# What is it called when you initialize things with =>

Tags: apex

I was looking for a way to do one-line variable creation and found this:

[Initialize Map<String, Integer>](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50829/initialize-mapstring-integer)

```
private Map<String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3};
```

What is this called? Is this listed in the documentation somewhere? I don't see this in [the documentation for Map](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_constructors) anywhere

How do curly brackets and `=>` work to initialize a Map, and presumably, other variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system itself seems to refer to this structure as `Map Literal Assignment`. Try to execute this flawed syntax:

```
Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String> { 'a', 'b' };
```

And you will get this compile error:

> expecting a `map literal assignment`, found `','`

---

They are often referred to as "hash rockets," though it is doubtful you will find documentation on that. You may find [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) helpful, but basically it explains what you already know.

Money quote:

> As with lists, you can populate map key-value pairs when the map is declared by using curly brace ({}) syntax. Within the curly braces, specify the key first, then specify the value for that key using =>.

Example:

```
Map<String, String> MyStrings = new Map<String, String>
{
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd'.toUpperCase()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

@Houseman Answering your question, when you declare Map data structure without assigning it value, you simply declare it has follows:

`Map<String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>();`

Where String is key and Integer is value;

Now, at the time of declaration if you want to assign values to the map, than you do as follows:

```
Map <String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3};
```

Where values before '=>' are key (String value) and value after '=>' are value assigned to the key in the map.

So basically statements or declaration within curly braces with use of '=>' is used to define key value pair for map.

There are other dynamic ways to do this which you can see in the document below:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_constructors